# how to apply default scrollbar style after it is once overided

Tags: wpf

I have overrided the default style of the scroll bar as below:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ScrollBar}" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
      ....
</Style>
```

based on above, all the scroll bars in my application uses the above overided scroll bar, but at one place i want the default scroll bar what the framework provides.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way then is to have the default scrollbar style in your resource dictionary and explicitly applying it on that instance. You can get Expression Blend to generate the template for it or maybe it's also in the documentation.